# Replacing Tricky column names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a problem replacing special characters in my column names. I've did this on many occasions but this one is stumping me.

I converted a groupby into a dataframe it created column names formatted like the ones below. I've bolded the column name as the additional **,** and **()** can make it difficult to figure out what it starts and ends.

[**('Bounce Rate', 'mean')**, **('% Exit', 'mean')**, **('Pageviews', 'sum')**, **('Unique Pageviews', 'sum')**,]

I've tried to use

```
df["('Bounce Rate', 'mean')"].str.replace("(",")
```

In this case all the column names return as 'nan'.

and

```
df.rename(columns={"('Bounce Rate', 'mean')": 'Bounce Rate', "('% Exit', 'mean')" : 'Exit', "('Pageviews', 'sum')" : 'Pageviews', "('Unique Pageviews', 'sum')" : 'Unique Pageviews'})
```

This seems to not change anything.

I know it's to do with the awkward characters but I don't know how to get around it.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Let's maybe take one step back - could you share the groupby that created columns with the above troublesome names ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a tuple as columns names

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[('Bounce Rate', 'mean')])
df = df.rename(columns={('Bounce Rate', 'mean'): 'Bounce Rate'})  #Tuple as key
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Bounce Rate]
Index: []
```

Comment:  YES so I do! I couldn't see it. Thank you for spotting that. It worked.